# IIS Redirects not working with ColdFusion 11

Tags: redirect, iis, coldfusion

Our IIS Redirects are not working with ColdFusion 11.  IIS 8.5 (on Win2012) redirects work fine only if there are no ColdFusion files specified in the URL.

The redirects are specified to redirect to a specific URL, to redirect to the exact destination, and to send an HTTP Response code of 301 Permanent Redirect.

However, with a .cfm file on the URL, the response is "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." The HTTP Response Code is 500 Internal Server Error. The web logs shows it as a 404.0 File Not Found error.

If we add the 'missing' .cfm file, the .cfm file gets processed ... thus, there is no redirect. It seems that the Connector is taking over before IIS can respond and process the Redirect.

Any ideas? thank you

Comment: Sounds like the same issue i was having with apache that i found no good solution for. Basically, IIS sees .cfm and hands it off to coldfusion before any redirects take place. with .htaccess the "solution" was to place the redirect in the vhost file. I'm not sure if such a solution even exists with iis.

Comment: @phpmeh this isn't a code problem. and, with that, this question might be off topic here since it's a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `<cflocation>` tag and give it a `301` status code if it meets the conditions that would cause you to want to redirect.

I've had the same problem myself and this worked for me, though you may not be in the same boat.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflocation

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We asked Adobe, and they said it was a bug in the Connector (Tomcat Connector that takes requests for ColdFusion files and sends them to ColdFusion instead of IIS).

We are using a workaround with URL Rewrites.

Comment: You should post that as an "answer", along with a brief description and/or snippet of the URL rewrite rule(s), to close out the thread and help the next guy with that issue.  (Answering your own question is allowed on S.O.)